# execute external command in new node-red module, what is the current directory?

Tags: node.js, node-red

I want to create a new node-red module, and I need to call an external python script within that node, how do I call it, if the script is in my node-red-node directory ?

my-node/myscript.py

is there a way to get the current directory of my node ?

I could spawn python, but I don't know where my script is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js has the `__dirname` as a global variable that represents the directory that the currently executing file is in.

You can use this to build a fully qualified path to your executable.

The docs are [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname)